# c# HttpWebRequest headers

Tags: c#, .net, header

Why the location is not listed on the response Headers?

My code:

```
        string url = "http://hehe.freevar.com/files.php";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "HEAD";
        Console.WriteLine(req.GetResponse().Headers);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location):

> The HTTP Location header is returned
>   in responses from an HTTP server under
>   two circumstances:
>
> 1. To force a web browser to load a different web page. It is passed as
>      part of the response by a web server
>      when the requested URI has:
>
>    - Moved temporarily, or
>    - Moved permanently

The [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2.aspx) class has a property `AllowAutoRedirect` which defaults to true:

> Set AllowAutoRedirect to true if you
>   want the request to automatically
>   follow HTTP redirection headers to the
>   new location of the resource.

This means you will never see the redirect request unless you set `AllowAutoRedirect`  to false before making the request:

```
string url = "http://hehe.freevar.com/files.php";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
req.Method = "HEAD";
Console.WriteLine(req.GetResponse().Headers);
```

Then you get the following response which does include **Location**:

```
Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=10000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2011 01:32:18 GMT
Location: http://www.160by2.com/post-registration.aspx
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.13
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `ResponseUri` property.

```
var responseUri = req.GetResponse().ResponseUri;
```

Comment: +1 depending on the scenario this might be what OP was actually looking for